# Symfony Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 36 of 40 bytes , moving from Mysql to PostgreSQL

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, symfony

I'm facing a problem while calling an api made in-house.
The log says :

```
[2017-02-07 16:04:39] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT h0_.id AS id_0, h0_.hash AS hash_1, h0_.request AS request_2, h0_.options AS options_3, h0_.serialized_response_body AS serialized_response_body_4, h0_.response AS response_5, h0_.sent_at AS sent_at_6 FROM http_request h0_ WHERE h0_.hash = ? ["dd3e36a5a38618974cae2b45f9cb3a67"] []
[2017-02-07 16:04:39] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 36 of 40 bytes" at /var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/ObjectType.php line 57 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\ContextErrorException(code: 0): Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 36 of 40 bytes at /var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/ObjectType.php:57)"} []
```

I'm kinda lost >.<

EDIT :

In my controller, I submit a form containing several information in order to do the process.

```
 /**
 * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"Review"})
 * @Security("is_granted('ROLE_REVIEW_CREATE')")
 */
public function postAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($this->getUser()->getBalance()->getTokens() == 0) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('The Review can not be created because you lack of tokens');
    }

    $review = new Review();
    $review->setCreatedBy($this->getUser());

    $reviewForm = $this->createForm(ReviewType::class, $review, [
        'csrf_protection' => false,
    ]);
    $reviewForm->submit($request->request->all());
    if ($reviewForm->isSubmitted() && $reviewForm->isValid()) {
        // If the user is in an organization, takes the organization analyzer environment, otherwise takes the user one.
        $analyzerEnvironment = $this->getUser()->getCompany() ? $this->getUser()->getCompany()->getAnalyzerEnvironment() : $this->getUser()->getAnalyzerEnvironment();

        $crawlingFlow = $this->get('app.manager.crawling_flow')->getCrawlingFlow();

        $this->get('app.manager.review')->process(
            $review,
            $crawlingFlow,
            $analyzerEnvironment
        );

        $reviewEncrypted = new ReviewEncrypted();
        $reviewEncrypted->setReliability($review->getReliability());
        $reviewEncrypted->setData($this->get('app.manager.review')->encrypt($review));
        $reviewEncrypted->setCreatedBy($this->getUser());
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($reviewEncrypted);
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
        $review->setId($reviewEncrypted->getId());

        if ($this->getUser()->getBalance()->getTokens() > 0) {
            $this->getUser()->getBalance()->setTokens($this->getUser()->getBalance()->getTokens() - 1);
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($this->getUser());
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
        }

        return $review;
    }

    return $reviewForm;
}
```

An when calling:

```
$crawlingFlow = $this->get('app.manager.crawling_flow')->getCrawlingFlow();

    $this->get('app.manager.review')->process(
        $review,
        $crawlingFlow,
        $analyzerEnvironment
    );
```

Several services are called, they send requests, do stuff like storing in DB, etc ...

Question is, is there something I forgot to do when I changed the db (from mysql to postgresql), or is it something else ?

Where can possibly come the unserialize() error ? Why ?

Thanks for the help :p

EDIT 2:

Here where the error comes from according to the log "vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/ObjectType.php line 57" :

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return serialize($value);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    if ($value === null) {
        return null;
    }

    $value = (is_resource($value)) ? stream_get_contents($value) : $value;
    $val = unserialize($value);
    if ($val === false && $value !== 'b:0;') {
        throw ConversionException::conversionFailed($value, $this->getName());
    }

    return $val;
}
```

Comment: anything about your code ?

Comment: Yeah the data might help.

Comment: Sorry post Edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one important difference between `text` of MySQL and PostgreSQL, and may be it's your case. PostgreSQL do not allow \0 in text field. So, on prepare stage pg driver cut string on first \0.

Unfortunately, `serialize` use \0 symbol internally.

```
class A {
  private $a = 'a';
  private $b = 'b';
}

$a = new A();

var_export(serialize($a));
```

will show 
`'O:1:"A":2:{s:4:"' . "\0" . 'A' . "\0" . 'a";s:1:"a";s:4:"' . "\0" . 'A' . "\0" . 'b";s:1:"b";}'`

MySQL insert of this sting will work fine:
`INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ('O:1:\"A\":2:{s:4:\"\0A\0a\";s:1:\"a\";s:4:\"\0A\0b\";s:1:\"b\";}')`

But Pg driver silently cut string and execute
`LOG:  execute pdo_stmt_00000001: INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ($1)`
`DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'O:1:"A":2:{s:4:"'`
or `INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ('O:1:"A":2:{s:4:"')` with prepare emulation.

As you can see - result is cut string and unserialize can't restore it.

Solution: use `bytea` datatype for Postgresql or add some kind of encode/decode of serialized string.

UPD: About `object` datatype in Doctrine http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#object

Comment: Thx, doing some research on how to implement the bytea way

Comment: I didn't get what to change?